# How to enable Spring Bean Validation before persisting but ignore for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

This is my scenario

```java
class B {
   @NotNull 
   String x;
}

class A {
    @Valid
    B b;

    @NotNull
    String y;
}
```

Now my Http POST request gets an object of `class A` as the payload. `String y` should be validated in the incoming HTTP request (and also validated before persisting to DB). However `String x` should NOT be validated in the incoming HTTP request (and only validated before persisting to DB) since `String x` will be null in the request and its value will be set by the business logic before the full `class A` object is persisted.

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize validation groups if you can edit these objects;

```
class B {
    @NotNull(groups = Ignored.class)
    String x;
}

class A {
    @Valid
    B b;

    @NotNull
    String y;
}
```

Where `Ignored` is;

```
import javax.validation.groups.Default;

public interface Ignored extends Default {
}
```

If your controller does not define this group, any annotation under it will be ignored, hence your requirement will be fulfilled, validation of `B.x` will be ignored in the request, but other fields of `A` will be validated. But I am not 100% sure that the validation will be applied in db side, can you try it?

Otherwise you can try to do;

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/etc")
    ResponseEntity<String> addA(@RequestBody A a) { //disabled validation here
        B tempB = a.getB();
        a.setB(null);
        validateA(a);
        a.setB(tempB);
        // continue logic
    }
}
```

where `validateA()` is;

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Validated
public class Validator {

    public void validateA(@Valid A a) {
        // nothing here
    }
}
```

Which is an ugly solution, but a solution nonetheless...

Answer (score 1):

I think you missing add @Vaild annotation on parameter which will be validated in controller layer.

```
@RestController
public class AController {

    @PostMapping("/a")
    ResponseEntity<String> addA(@Valid @RequestBody A a) {
        // persisting the a entity 
        return ResponseEntity.ok("A is valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it would not affect if "@Valid" annotation was not prefixed the arguments, @Jonathan explained it.

To enable validation before persist, it's work like this way:

```
@Repository
@Validated
public MyDao {
    public void insertA(@Valid A a){
        //logic here
    }

}
```

@Validated(org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated) is the key to enable arguments validation. It works for me.